# Android Java, very simple code. but where goes wrong?

Tags: android, for-loop

I using a web services to get the value, make the long story short. I can get the value from webservices, for this case, the value for strVersion is 1(the for loop only return 1 record since there is only 1 record).

Now here is the problem, the result always return "Wrong: 1" instead of "OK: 1", come someone please tell me why? the datatype in MYSQL for this field is Varchar.

```
    AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

    final String[] strVersion = new String[resultString.getPropertyCount()];

    for(int i =0; i<resultString.getPropertyCount(); i++)
    {
        SoapObject array = (SoapObject) resultString .getProperty(i);
        strVersion[i] = array.getProperty(0).toString();                    
        if(strVersion[i] == "1")
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK: " + strVersion[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong: " + strVersion[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `String` comparison using `equals()`.

Change this:

```
if(strVersion[i] == "1")
```

to

```
if(strVersion[i].equals("1"))
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) for more information.

`==` compares references,not the values. In your case, you want to check for the value equality, not the reference equality.

Comment: been doing c# for a very long time. kinda confuse sometime. Thanks dude! :)